# MongoDB group documents by id and merge matching array elements from the documents

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use the Mongo aggregate framework to group a document by id and then have the 'events' array from each document merged into one array. I have tried different group accumulators; push, first, last etc. With push it results in an array of arrays. But I want a single array with all the events objects.
MongoDB 4.4

Documents

```
{
        _id: 123,
        name: "John",
        events: [
            {
                start: "2020-01-01",
                end: "2020-01-01"
            },
            {
                start: "2020-01-01",
                end: "2020-01-01"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 123,
        name: "John",
        events: [
            {
                start: "2020-01-21",
                end: "2020-01-21"
            },
        ]
    },
        {
            _id: 456,
            name: "Ben",
            events: [
                {
                    start: "2020-01-21",
                    end: "2020-01-21"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: 456,
            name: "Ben",
            events: [
                {
                    start: "2020-02-01",
                    end: "2020-02-01"
                },
            ]
        },
```

My group aggregate

```
'$group': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'resourceName': {
            '$first': '$name',
        },
        'events': {
            '$push': "$events"
        }
    }
```

Desired output

```
[
    {
        _id: 123,
        name: "John",
        events: [
            {
                start: "2020-01-01",
                end: "2020-01-01"
            },
            {
                start: "2020-01-01",
                end: "2020-01-01"
            },
            {
                start: "2020-01-21",
                end: "2020-01-21"
            },
        ]
    },
        {
            _id: 456,
            name: "Ben",
            events: [
                {
                    start: "2020-02-01",
                    end: "2020-02-01"
                },
                {
                    start: "2020-01-21",
                    end: "2020-01-21"
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/

Comment: Thanks but concatArrays is coming as an unknown group operator.

Comment: Your data has duplicate _ids and cannot be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Use $unwind to flatten out the source arrays then $addToSet to remove duplicates.

Data:

```
cc.insert_many([{
  foo: 1,
  bar: [10, 11],
}, {
  foo: 1,
  bar: [10, 21],
}, {
  foo: 2,
  bar: [30, 31],
}])
```

```
[{"$unwind"=>"$bar"},
 {"$group"=>{"_id"=>"$foo", "bar"=>{"$addToSet"=>"$bar"}}}]

[{"_id"=>2, "bar"=>[30, 31]}, {"_id"=>1, "bar"=>[21, 10, 11]}]
```